# how can a user change their password in this website?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I'm creating a website using Spring Boot. I have a template (thymeleaf) in which users can change their password. But when the user writes a new password the password doesn't change. It redirects to my homepage but nothing happens. There is no error.

My back end for changing passwords:

`@Controller`

```
@GetMapping("/reset") public String infoLogin(Model model){ 
model.addAttribute("users",new Users()); return "login/reset";
}

@PostMapping("/reset/{username}") public String pass(@PathVariable("username") String username){ 
userService.findUsername(username); return "redirect:/index"; 
}
```

`@Service`

```
@Transactional @PreAuthorize("#username == authentication.name") public Users findUsername(String username){ 
return this.usersRepo.findByUsername(username); 
}
```

`@Repository`

```
@Repository public interface UsersRepo extends JpaRepository<Users,Long> {

Users findByUsername(String username);
}
```

security configs:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {
    
    private final UserService userService;
    
    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig( UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/guest/**","/index/**","/images/**","/css/**","/fonts/**","/js/**","/scripts/**","/server/**","/src/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/*","/user/*").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user/*").hasAuthority("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                          .and().formLogin().loginPage("/guest/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/index",true).permitAll()
                .and().rememberMe().rememberMeCookieName("remember").rememberMeParameter("remember")
                .and().logout().deleteCookies("remember").permitAll()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/guest/403");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       User.UserBuilder userBuilder=User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();
       auth.userDetailsService(userService);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

template:

```html
<form method="post"  th:action="@{/user/reset/{username}(username=${#authentication.principal.getUsername})}" th:object="${users}">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" th:field="*{username}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>New Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" th:field="*{password}" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-right">
        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

In the database, it roughly looks like the following:

| id | email | username | password | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | something@gmail.com | mehdi22 | 12345678 | ... |

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_users")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Users implements Serializable, UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private boolean enabled =true;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 4,max = 10)
    private String username;
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 2,max = 20)
    private String name;
    @Email
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 8,max = 30)
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Posts> posts;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Roles.class,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "authorities",joinColumns =
    @JoinColumn(name = "username",referencedColumnName = "username") )
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private List<Roles> roles;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(String username, String name, String email, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<Posts> getPosts() {
        return posts;
    }

    public void setPosts(List<Posts> posts) {
        this.posts = posts;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enable) {
        this.enabled = enable;
    }

    public List<Roles> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Roles> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return roles;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: Don't store passwords in clear-text in your database. Instead, use hashing with a proper `PasswordEncoder` (not `NoOpPasswordEncoder`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when the user writes a new password the password doesn't change.

You are just not changing the password anywhere. When you send the form and `/reset/{username}` is called, you are not even looking at the password.

```java
@PostMapping("/reset/{username}")
public String pass(@PathVariable("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password){ 
    userService.changePassword(username,password);
    return "redirect:/index"; 
}
```

and in your service:

```java
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Transactional
@PreAuthorize("#username == authentication.name")
public void changePassword(String username, String password){ 
    Users user= this.usersRepo.findByUsername(username); 
    user.setPassword(this.passwordEncoder.encode(password));
    this.usersRepo.save(user);
}
```

Aside from that, you should hash your password. Imagine someone unauthorized gets access to your database. They can just access all your user's passwords.

For hashing passwords, change your `PasswordEncoder` to not use `NoOpPasswordEncoder`

```java
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

Also note that you shouldn't show users their own passwords (or hashes).

For this, change

```java
<input type="password" id="password" th:field="*{password}" class="form-control">
```

to

```java
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control">
```

I would also recommend you to not rely on `@PreAuthorize` for checking that the user actually changed their own password. Instead, I would do something like:

```java
@PostMapping("/reset")
public String pass(Authentication authentication, @RequestParam("password") String password){ 
    userService.changePassword(authentication.getName(), password);
    return "redirect:/index"; 
}
```

this always changes the password of the current user. it also doesn't require the username to be sent from the frontend allowing you to simplify your form:

```html
<form method="post" th:action="@{/user/reset" th:object="${users}">
```

Without `th:object`, the whole form could look like this:

```html
<form method="post" th:action="@{/user/reset"">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <label th:text="${users.username}"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>New Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-right">
        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: which library did you use for (Authentication authentication) ?

Comment: [`Authentication`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/6.0.0/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) is a class present with Spring Security (in `org.springframework.security.core`). Alternatively, you could use `Principal` (present in the JVM system libraries). - It should be present in your project.